# CSS Iris wipe effect - (Light at the end of the tunnel)

Tags: css

I'd like to create a CSS effect which can somehow replicate the "end of the tunnel" effect similar to this:

[image: tunnel effect]

I'm trying to look online for viable solution but without any results.

I'm starting from scratch so i just have 2 div currently which have different backgrounds, and i want the one on top to slowly disappear.

Any idea or suggestion to get started?

here's the initial code which anyway won't really be helpful:

module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<main> 
<div></div> <!--this one should do the tunnel thing -->
<div>my content will be here</div>
</main>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far? Surely you have at least *some* code you can share in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: similar to .. a 2h youtube video?

Comment: i'm refactoring my portfolio using angular and the code is pretty messy, but here's the link to the repo which actually [works](https://github.com/koop4/koop4.github.io/tree/refactorangular/src/app)

I did not try anything because I really don't know where to start, and I'm not looking for "the answer" but just for someone that can address me to the idea

Comment: @temaniAfif  It's the whole day I'm looking around for something similar.
If there were anything i wouldn't have asked.  If it's not clear what's the effect I am trying to achieve i will restate the question

Comment: don't share a link to a youtube video where we need to *find* what you want. try to describe it here using screenshot of Gif and by showing your code

Comment: if anyone has an angular 7 plunker i ll make a sample app with my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only about background and image, you can consider multiple background layer where you can use a radial-gradient that you expand:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%,#000 1.5%),
    url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:100% 100%,cover;
  transition:1s all;
}
body:hover {
  background-size:10000% 10000%, cover;
}
```

With content you can consider a layer above using pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  color:#fff;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%,#000 1.5%);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover::before {
  background-size:10000% 10000%, cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h1>A title</h1>
<p>some content some content some content some content some content</p>
</div>
```

Here is another idea using and box-shadow:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 200vh #000;
  transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover::before {
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h1>A title</h1>
<p>some content some content some content some content some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunatly the idea is to have the content behinde and to use some sort of z index on the div which replicate the tunnel effect.

Comment: @Koop4 check the update, it's an idea that you can adjust like you want

Comment: thanks, I knew I had to understand more the pseuo elements.
This is what I was looking for.
I m a little upset with you because now I have the solution already! Thanks man

Comment: @Koop4 I have also added another way

Comment: is it possible to make them do what they do using animation? (and animation delay)?
Please don't provide me the code for this one too, just a yes or no answer, otherwise i ll feel helpless >,<

Comment: Yes it is replace all the `hover` with animation. Also maybe look into `css-clip` as a solution it might be more versatile.

Comment: @Koop4 yes it's possible, look at keyframes and animation, it's easy to use